# Click on h:panelgroup

Tags: jsf-2.2

I am struggling to get the click event on h:panelgroup which will call a method in my managedbean. I don't want binding as it is only for property.

Also can someone explain the function of below line.

`<f:ajax event="click" render="@all" listener="#{ABC.abc}" />`

This is taking click listener on the whole page. I only need it to trigger when the input is clicked. So after this was not working I am trying to get a click on panelgroup. Is there any other way.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get an answer so far?

Answer (score 0):

So figured it out why it was taking click on whole page. I was not wrapping f:ajax call in jsf component. So it was attacking to main h:panelgroup. Wrapped it around a new panelgroup and it started working fine.

But I am getting click twice on each call. :/